# How can we divide a segment of an arbitrary length in the ratio $1:\sqrt a$, where $a$ is not a perfect square?

Tags: geometric-construction

The question in the title is asking in general. The question given:

> Divide a segment of length 8cm in the ratio $1:\sqrt{12}$

How can it be done?

Comment: What tools are you given with which to divide the segment (I would presume ruler and compass, but that's not explicit), and what have you tried so far? What do you know about $\sqrt{12}$?

Comment: Also, when you say 'ratio $1:\sqrt{12}$', does that mean finding a segment that's $1/\sqrt{12}$ of the total length or dividing it into two lengths whose ratio is $1/\sqrt{12}$? These are entirely different problems...

Comment: A compass and a ruler

Comment: Dividing the segment into two parts whose ratio is 1: sqrt 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that $\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt3$ and it is easy to get a segment length $\sqrt3$ using equilateral triangles.

Draw equilateral triangles $ABC,DBC$ side 2 (with $A,D$ on opposite sides of $BC$). Then $AD=2\sqrt3$. Take $E$ on the line $AD$ with $D$ between $A$ and $E$ so that $DE=1$.

Now if $AF$ has length 8 (or any other length), draw a line through $D$ parallel to $EF$ intersecting $AF$ at $X$. Evidently $AX/XF=AD/DE=2\sqrt3$.